# Handling MMU translation faults in instruction stream - what happens to MMU?

Tags: caching, cpu, tlb, mmu

This question is not specific to any CPU implementation, but CPU-specific answers are welcomed.

I am currently implementing a full MMU-enabled CPU, and a simple issue arose.

So, imagine the situation where a simple TLB miss happens caused by the instruction stream (or instruction cache). This would trigger a TLB miss. Now, if the PTE is not found, some exception will be triggered, like a "Page Translation Fault". So far, no problem at all.

Now, in order to call the fault handler, the instruction stream (or cache) needs to fetch the exception handler code. For that it will need to search again for the relevant PTE entry in TLB, and eventually another table walk.

Imagine that, again, the PTE entry is not found. One would expect some other exception handler to be called.

Now, on this last exception handler, since the handler itself might not be found or be valid, does MMU gets disabled before the handler is fetched and executed (thus bypassing everyting MMU does, including Phys-Virt mapping), or is there another technique (non-fatal) to deal with this situation ?

Alvie

Answer (score 1):

I can't say this with certainty about real world operating system, but from the little experience in looking at small kernels, the emphasis always seems to be in ensuring that the page fault handler by itself is never paged out and is always in a location that never raises a page fault. This would make sure that a situation as described in your problem never arises.

In general, it seems to make sense that some part of the core kernel code resides statically on the physical memory with known mapping; but given that you were anyway trying to write a full blown virtual memory enabled OS, I guess you would know be knowing that.

Comment: My question is actually hardware-related, not software-related.
So, in case we cannot properly handle the fault the only option seems to be a full reset. I was wondering if, for a specific scenario, the MMU could be disabled to avoid this from happening. Could be mapped (hard) to firmware code, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I'm aware of:

1. MMU is disabled automatically when interrupt/exception occur. So fault handler (data abort handler) has to be placed at known physical address and spurious MMU faults are out of question. That's a responsibility of a handler to reenable MMU before returning from an exception or for handler usage itself. That behaviour, in real life, quite a pain in an ass... 
   For example 'Microblaze' arch does exactly that.
2. MMU is not disabled automatically. The trick is to have 2 set of TLB tables. TLB1 has kernel mapping tables, TLB0 is made for an user apps mapping tables. Respectively kernel & user apps should have appropriate linkage to exclude the overlapping of virtual addresses between each other.
   When user app does a sh** and cause a MMU fault, exception occurs. Abort/fault handler is in kernel memory space so handler code will be accessed with different TLB. You should be damn sure that kernel TLB is correct :) 
   If kernel exception handler generates exception itself then there is a probability of spurious data and/or instruction aborts. 
   In practice however, "ARM-Ax" CPUs, for instance, mask exceptions/interrupts when they are taken. I think spurious exceptions do not occur, I've never tested that in practice though.
   And well HW watchdog might give you a favour...